# AssertEquals gives TransactionTooLargeException on big strings on Instrumented Unit Tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

I have a strange behavior with Android Studio and Unit Testing.

I am doing instrumented unit tests (`AndroidJUnitRunner`) on Android using a large json data (>800kb), and when I try to assert equality with random data:

```
assertEquals("ghgg", jsonData.toString());
```

It crashes with `java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException`.

While the inequality assertion does not crashes and passes green.

```
assertNotEquals("ghgg", jsonData.toString());
```

Now, if I do the same test, but with just plain non-instrumented junit, the inequality assertion does not crashes and passes green as before, and the equality assertion does not pass (red), but it does not give exception.

```
assertEquals("ghgg", jsonData.toString());
```

How come in instrumented tests, `assertEquals` can not handle big strings, while `assertNotEquals` can ?

Comment: Interesting question, but very very specific. My gut feeling is that you wont receive much helpful feedback here. I would try asking on the JUnit forum (or do they have a google group?!) and probably in some Android studio expert forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you only see the difference in behaviour for failing asserts?

If so this may be due to a implementation detail of the built in JUnit asserts.

The failure path is different for equals and not equals.

Equals creates a `ComparisonFailure` which goes on to do some processing of **both** the expected and actual values.

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected,
        Object actual) {
    if (equalsRegardingNull(expected, actual)) {
        return;
    } else if (expected instanceof String && actual instanceof String) {
        String cleanMessage = message == null ? "" : message;
        throw new ComparisonFailure(cleanMessage, (String) expected,
                (String) actual);
    } else {
        failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
    }
}
```

While not equals generates a failure messeage using **only** the actual value.

```
static public void assertNotEquals(String message, Object unexpected,
    Object actual) {
  if (equalsRegardingNull(unexpected, actual)) {
      failEquals(message, actual);
  }
}

private static void failEquals(String message, Object actual) {
  String formatted = "Values should be different. ";
  if (message != null) {
      formatted = message + ". ";
  }

  formatted += "Actual: " + actual;
  fail(formatted);
}
```

This is true for junit 4.12. It may not be true for earlier and/or later versions.

Comment: Is this the actual source code of the 2 assert methods ?

Comment: @Yahia - yes, the relevant bits.